# Cannot close the Db correctly

Tags: android, sqlite

Following is my code,

```
    public class CommentsDataSource {

        private SQLiteDatabase database;
        private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
        private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT };

        public CommentsDataSource(Context context) {
            dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
        }

        public void open() throws SQLException {
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        public void close() {
            if (database != null) {
                database.close();

            }
            dbHelper.close();

        }

        public String getComment_1() {
            List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
                    allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
                comments.add(comment);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();

            return comments.get(0).getComment();
        }

        private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));

            return comment;
        }
public class MyService extends BackgroundService implements LocationListener {
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        context = getApplicationContext();
        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(context);
        gps = new GPSTracker(context);
        datasource.open();
        mHelloTo = datasource.getComment_1();
        datasource.close();
    }
}
```

In the Above Code  use to retrieve some data from database inside a Background Service. It Works Fine but Sometimes it gives the Following Error even though i close the cursor database and dbhelper correctly.

```
  01-08 14:31:58.691: E/SQLiteDatabase(13854): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/org.apache.cordova.example/databases/commments.db'
```

Comment: not sure for this, but can you try to move the "cursorToComment" code inside getComment_1() (a.k.a. destroy the "cursorToComment" method)

Answer (score 1):

This only happens on platforms before JellyBean. JellyBean and later have this error message removed.

Even though it is logged with error log level and contains exception stacktrace, it is not an exception that was thrown. `SQLiteDatabase` constructor just stores the stacktrace of its caller in a member variable exception and in finalizer logs the stacktrace in case the database is still open.

You can see the stacktrace to see where the unclosed database was opened.

To get specific help with your code, include relevant parts of `MySQLiteHelper` in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
public String getComment_1() {

       open(); // open database

        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
            comments.add(comment);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();

       close(); // close database

        return comments.get(0).getComment();


    }
```

Also what `dbHelper.close();` does? You're closing the connection with the db calling `database.close()` so why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the methods correctly, but please change the `open()` and `close()` methods to the following :

```
public void open() throws SQLException {
  dbHelper= new MySQLiteHelper (ctx);
  database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
}

public void close() {
  dbHelper.close();
}
```

But instead of opening and closing the database each time you make a read/write operation, I'd recommend you `open()` the database once in your `Application.onCreate()`. The closing will be done automatically when your application exits or is closed by Android OS. Since SQLite data integrity, you don't have to worry about losing data.